# I get some warnings when i use %llu as format specifier for unsigned long long with printf() function in C

Tags: c, format, format-specifiers

I get some warnings from my IDE (Code:Blocks, Win64) when i use `%llu` as format specifier for `unsigned long long` in C with `printf()`.

```
warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
warning: too many arguments for format
```

But `%llu` should be the right one for `unsigned long long`...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fibonacciNumber(int n)
{
    unsigned long long fib1 = 0, fib2 = 1;

    if (n < 1)
        return;

    printf("%lld ", fib1);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%lld ", fib2);

        unsigned long long nextNum = fib1 + fib2;
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = nextNum;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numbers, clearBuffer;
    char answer;

    do
    {
        printf("Fibonacci sequence calculator - Enter a number :");
        scanf("%i",&numbers);

        fibonacciNumber(numbers);

        while ((clearBuffer = getchar()) != EOF && clearBuffer != '\n');

        printf("\n\nNew calculation? [y / n]");
        scanf("%c",&answer);

    }while ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the actual code you're asking about, in the form of a [mre]. Then copy-paste (as *text!*) the full and complete build log for that example.

Comment: The code you currently have posted as `%lld` and not `%llu` in the line `printf("%lld ", fib2);`.  I don't currently see any other uses.

Comment: What C standard version do you use for compilation?

Comment: Sounds like you are using an old mingw compiler or perhaps the old Microsoft CRT that only had C90 support.

Comment: Use `%llu` for unsigned long long int.  `%lld` is for signed long long int.

Comment: You compile with ```lld```, not ```llu```. That being said, if your compiler doesn't support these, compile the program with the flag ```std=c17```.

Comment: I use the GNU GCC Compiler g++ (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0

Comment: Now it works! I hooked on the c11 std in the compiler settings!

Comment: @Heimo, try `numbers = 94`.  Do you get `-6246583658587674878` or `12200160415121876738`?